# How to compare 2 dynamically allocated array's memory locations

Tags: c

For example, let's say I have two arrays, `int* foo` and `int* bar` which are dynamically allocated. Foo and bar are copies of each other.

How do I compare foo's memory location and bar's memory location?

Comment: You can compare these pointers directly just by using `==`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by comparing their memory location? Do you want to test whether `foo` and `bar` refer to the same array?

Comment: FYI, you should not speak of “foo’s memory location” or “bar’s memory location” unless you mean the location where the `foo` pointer is or the location where the `bar` pointer is. `foo` and `bar` are objects; they are pointers that are defined by the declarations `int *foo;` and `int *bar;`. Those objects have memory locations of their own, distinct from anything they point to. Once they are assigned non-null values, they **point to** memory locations. Then you can ask about comparing “the location that `foo` points to” and “the location that `bar` points to.”

Comment: `int*` is *not* an array. It's a pointer *to* something that can be *treated like* an array.

Answer (score -1):

You can compare the addresses in each array, by testing the pointer value.
if (foo == bar)
Can you add details to your question, what kind of comparison would you make?